# Error while installing 'terrier3.5'

Tags: java, ubuntu-12.04, semantic-analysis

I am trying to install terrier 3.5. i get the following error while doing so and dont know what to do to fix it.

```
terrier-3.5/lib/fastutil5-5.0.9.jar
terrier-3.5/lib/findbugs-1.3.2-annotations.jar
terrier-3.5/lib/hadoop-0.20.2+228-core.jar

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Could someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

The solution is

Download Terrier again, and then install it.
It should work. 
There were some packets missing while download.